# Change name of any file in batch with input

Tags: batch-file

I would like to make a batch file that changes every PDF file in a folder.

The PDF have a random number and should look like this after:

```
id_3Q09_iid_1_dat_04-01-2017_nm-SUB_certificate.pdf
```

Where I want to input the "`3Q09`"  "`1`" (`IDD`) and the Date.

So when I open the batch file I get a question about what the ID, IDD and date should be, and it changes every PDF file in the folder.

I tried some scripts but they all try to rename a known file 
This is the script i used:

```
@Echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 
set /p ID="Product ID: " 
set /p IID="IID: " 
set /p Datum="Keuringsdatum: "
Rn "!Name:id_%ID%_%IID%_dat_%Datum%_nm-SUB_certificate.!" )
```

Comment: Can you show us the scripts that you have tried?

Comment: Please show the content of your mentioned scripts...

Comment: I have added the code to the orignal post @Lamer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure if this is exactly what you're intending to do but you could use a for-loop to iterate through all PDF files within a specific folder.

**batch-file**

```
@(setlocal disabledelayedexpansion
  set "source=folder\*.pdf"
  set /p "id=Product ID: "
  set /p "iid=IID: "
  set /p "dat=Date: "
  prompt $
)

@for %%e in ("%source%") do rename "%%~fe" "id_%id%_iid_%iid%_dat_%dat%_nm-%%~nxe"
@prompt
```

**example output**

```
Product ID: 3Q09
IID: 1
Date: 04-01-2017

rename "d:\pdf\folder\SUB_certificate.pdf" "id_3Q09_iid_1_dat_04-01-2017_nm-SUB_
certificate.pdf"

rename "d:\pdf\folder\test (!!^^!!) file.pdf" "id_3Q09_iid_1_dat_04-01-2017_nm-t
est (!!^^!!) file.pdf"
```

---

> after the rename i want them to cut and paste them to a other folder.
>   can i do this with the MV command ?

You can simply use the `move` command if you want to move the files to another folder while renaming them. Note the following from the help message of the `move` command:

> If you are moving only one file, you can also include a filename if
>   you want to rename the file when you move it.

**batch-file (move instead of rename)**

```
@(setlocal disabledelayedexpansion
  set "source=folder\*.pdf"
  set "dest=output"
  set /p "id=Product ID: "
  set /p "iid=IID: "
  set /p "dat=Date: "
  prompt $
)

@for %%e in ("%source%") do move "%%~fe" "%dest%\id_%id%_iid_%iid%_dat_%dat%_nm-%%~nxe"
@prompt
```

Comment: Hello @treintje thank you so much that works perfect!

Comment: Hello @treintje is it also possible to output it to a other folder?

Comment: @Nextria You're welcome. What do you mean with "output it to a other folder" exactly? Do you mean you want to move the files instead of renaming them (cut and paste) or copy them to another folder with a different name?

Comment: after the rename i want them to cut and paste them to a other folder.
can i do this with the MV command ?

Comment: @Nextria You will need to use the `move` command instead of `rename`. I've updated my answer accordingly.